# kendo grid multiple column sort

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid and I have enabled multiple sort.

**Code:**

```
sortable: {
   mode: "multiple",
   allowUnsort: true
}
```

As I am writing server-side code to send response for the sort actions. For this I want to know the maximum number of columns supported by Kendo Grid for multiple sorting. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What leads you to believe that there is a limit imposed by Kendo?